# Proving Elementary question regarding non empty finite sets by contradiction

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am aware this post is similar to my previous one,but I am still a bit confused about the problem and would appreciate some help!

Can somebody help me correct my attempts at proving the following result? Much appreciated.

**Theorem.** Suppose $X$ is a nonempty finite set. Let $n$ be the least natural number such that there is a one-to-one function $f: X \rightarrow $ {$1,2,3,...,n$}. With the number of elements in $X$ being |$X$|$=n$, prove that $f$ must be onto.

**My Attempt:**

Suppose for contradiction that $f$ is not onto,then there exist some elements in the codomain {$1,2,3,...,n$} such that no elements of the domain map to them. Let $1 \le i \le n$ be the largest element of the codomain such that $i \notin ran(f)$.

**[case $i=n$].** If $i=n$, then by definition $n \notin ran(f)$.Since n is the least natural number that ensures $f$ to be one-to-one, it must be the case that $n \in ran(f)$ providing the contradiction sought.

**[case $i<n$].**  the book gives the hint :

> if $i<n$,let $a \in X$ be such that $f(a)=n$.Define a one-to-one
>   function $g : X\rightarrow$ {$1,2,...,n-1$}.

With $i<n$ then by definition $i \notin ran(f)$ but,there is an element $a \in X$ such that $f(a)=n$ or more succintly that $n \in ran(f)$.

**Is this reasoning correct :** Since $i \notin ran(f)$,then there is no element in the domain $X$ that maps to it.Therefore one can remove this element from the codomain of $f$ without changing the one-to-one nature of the function. Now let $g:X \rightarrow ${$1,2,3,...,n-1$} defined by $g(a)=n-1=i$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ for all other $x \in X$. Since n-1 is the least natural number for which a one-to-one function can be constructed from $X$,this contradicts the initial assumption that $n$ is the appropriate least natural number.As a consequence we reject the assumption of $f$ being not onto in the case where $1 \lt n$ as well.

this feels wrong somewhere...

Thank you

Comment: Being $X$ finite, the intuition is quite simple... Assume for simplicity that there is only **one** $i \le n$ such that $i$ has no corresponding element in $X$. Then, consider $a \in X$ such that $f(a)=n$ and assign $i$ to $a$ (i.e. define $g(x)$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for every $x \in X$ such that $x \ne a$ and $g(a)=i$). In this way, we have "freed" $n$ and $g$ is still one-to-one. But $g : X \to \{ 1, 2, \ldots, n-1 \}$ contradicting the assumption that $n$ is the least natural number such that ...

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mauro,does that mean my answer was right then or something wrong ?